# Does cancelling F-1 visa extension interview void my current visa?

Tags: visas, f1-visas, visa-cancellation, interview

The end date on my I-20 is May 2023.
My current F-1 visa expires in June 2022.

I scheduled an interview to extend my visa on the 9th of May 2022, but due to personal reasons I cannot attend that.
Therefore I decided to cancel it.

Will this somehow void my current visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your visa will remain valid until its expiration date in June 2022. (Of course, US visas are only for entry, so if you are not going to leave and re-enter the US, then the visa validity doesn't matter anyway.)